# Padrão para métodos boleanos

Tags: c#, java

Caros, qual o padrão que devo utilizar para nomear métodos que retornam um boleano (true ou false) ?

Por exemplo, tenho um método que verifica se a fatura está vencida.

Possíveis nomes que pensei:

- FaturaVencida
- IsFaturaVencida
- FaturaEstaVencida
- EhFaturaVencida

Atualmente uso Ruby e lá o nome ficaria `fatura_vencida?`.
Mas no novo projeto vamos usar C# ou Java.

Obrigado

Comment: Apesar de misturar inglês e português ficaria com a segunda opção, mas só comentei mesmo porque esse "Eh" é tenso.

Comment: Qual você deve usar fica difícil dizer, não podemos decidir por você mas nessa pergunta indicada tem várias informações sobre nomenclatura. E tem o que é mais importante, escolha uma forma e mantenha a consistência.

Comment: Experiencias passadas dizem-me que programar em portugues nunca e' uma boa opcao...